# dispatch_async still blocking my UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I'm rather new to GCD and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong. My code is something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                if([manager updateRecord:foodRecord]) // this function will connect to a web server, and might take a few seconds. If I remove it, the UI will be smooth as butter
                {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [cell expandAnimation]; // this function calls a series of UIView animateWithDuration to basically scale the cell and then call a reloadData when it's done
                    });
                }
            });
```

Any idea why it still causes synchronous like behavior? There seems to be no difference before and after I tried to use GCD.

Comment: What precisely is this "synchronous-like behavior"? Are you saying that you have a line of code after this `dispatch_async` that is not being reached? Regardless, the problem does not rest in the above code. Perhaps in `updateRecord` method. You can always use Instruments with the "Record waiting threads" option as illustrated in WWDC 2012 video [Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211).

Comment: Is the manager's -updateRecord method thread-safe? If not so, do you instantiating and accessing manager's resources on the same thread?

Comment: Please share your code in `updateRecord` method.. There seems some problem.

Comment: When the UI seems blocked, click the "Pause program execution" button in Xcode.  What does the main thread's stack look like?

Comment: `What precisely is this "synchronous-like behavior"? `
When I clicked on a cell, it lags. If I click several cells in succession, it lags more. The animation is not smooth. Timers also stopped incrementing.

Yes, the updateRecord method is thread-safe. Nothing inside is done in the main thread.

`When the UI seems blocked, click the "Pause program execution" button in Xcode.`
Thank you, I've found the "problem".

Comment: I've managed to solve my problem. The issue isn't with the code I've listed above, but somewhere else a socket was listening for instructions, and it was running on the main thread processing data.

Not sure why my question got downvoted, can anyone elaborate so I don't make such a mistake again?

Thank you all for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your idea of "synchronous like behavior" is but the main benefit of the `dispatch_async` pattern as you have is that animations (such as tableView scrolling and other transitions) can continue without stuttering and for the end user the app feels responsive. It will not be able to show any more data or update a UI based on the data available until the 5 second web server call has finished.

Perhaps you need to update the cells with a "loading Data" type message or display an activity indicator before the first dispatch_async call to keep the user informed.

Then after the `dispatch_async` as started the UI should still feel responsive (eg. scrollable tableView etc.) for the user while waiting <5 seconds. Then in the `dispatch_async` back to the Main queue this "loading" UI state could be removed (insert designer magic here) and then call your `[cell expandAnimation];` to finish it off.

If you are still seeing stuttering on the UI then maybe the `[manager updateRecord:foodRecord]` is doing very heavy processing on the return web data which could be further investigated with something like the TimeProfiler instrument but I think that's a separate issue.

Comment: Thank you, your answer provided some very useful information for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't the gcd code nor the user code as shown above.

The issue was another socket listening for instructions, and when the `updateRecord` method was called, the socket was also receiving some instructions which was being done on the main thread. It wasn't instantaneous, hence the illusion that the gcd code not working for some reason. This also slightly increased the difficulty of solving the issue since the code above is not directly related to the problem.

So if you are reading this, think more broadly on how your app is working (internally), and check what else could be running in the app!